# Latex appendix number only ".1"

Tags: latex

I have a Problem with my appendix. 
This Code shows me only ".1" with no A. I can´t find something that works to show the A, like "A.1".

```
\appendix
\section{Konversation mit Pauker J. der Firma Alfresco}
\includegraphics[scale=0,75]{../Bilder/KonversationAlfrescoPaukerJ.pdf}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a answer about my question.

I have to add:

```
\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\section{Title}
```